# How to get complete node list of elements from inside vuedraggable template

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, draggable, vuedraggable

I'm using vuedraggable (https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next) and trying to get a NodeList of all elements rendered inside the draggable component.

The usual Vue3 way would be to use template refs on the v-for list, like described here: (https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for)

When using the template ref on the vuedraggabel component, I'm only getting one element back, but not the whole list of elements.

Template:

```
<draggable
        :list="previewArray"
        group="images"
        @start="drag = true"
        @end="drag = false"
        item-key="id"
        class="upload_previews"
      >
        <template #item="{ element }">
          
            <img
              class="preview"
              :src="element"
              ref="imgRefs"
            />
            
         </template>
</draggable>
```

script setup:

```
let imgRefs = ref([]);

let previewArray = ['http://images/image1.jpg','http://images/image2.jpg']

console.log('imgRefs')  //prints only one image
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Checkout this link 
https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next/issues/120

Answer (score 0):

Since u use https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next it should be Vue3.
As described [here](https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/guide/migration/array-refs.html):
Vue 3 will no longer automatically create an array in $refs when using loops. To retrieve multiple refs from a single binding, bind ref to a function